# Prototype Pattern, Using 'this' within a jQuery $.each function

Tags: javascript, jquery, design-patterns, prototype, this

I want to build up a `<select>` via XML data within my `object`.  I want to use the Prototype Pattern for all of this and I have to admit I'm very new at Patterns.  Here's what I have:

**HTML Sample:**

```
<select id="ddFullName" name="Full_Name" ></select>
```

**XML sample:**

```
<names>
  <nameDetails name="Name 01" phone="555-867-5309" email="none@nothing.no" />
  <nameDetails name="Name 02" phone="555-867-5309" email="none@nothing.no" />
  <nameDetails name="Name 03" phone="555-867-5309" email="none@nothing.no" />
  <nameDetails name="Name 04" phone="555-867-5309" email="none@nothing.no" />
  <nameDetails name="Name 05" phone="555-867-5309" email="none@nothing.no" />
</names>
```

**JavaScript Sample:**

```
function buildNameDropdown(data, elem) { 
    this.data = data;
    this.name = $(data).find('nameDetails');
    this.elem = elem;

    buildNameDropdown.prototype.init = function()
    {
        //Working as desired
        $(this.elem).append($('<option value=""> ----- Select a Name ----- </option>')); 
        //Not working
        $(this.name).each(function()
        {
            //$(this) = the object, not 'this.name'
            $(this.elem).append($('<option value="' + $(this).attr('name') + '">' + $(this).attr('name') + '</option>'));

        });
        $(this.elem).combobox(); // from jQuery UI combobox extension
    };
};


var myNameDropdown = new buildNameDropdown(data, "#ddFullName");
myNameDropdown.init();
```

how am I suppose to reference 'this' as the selector for the each function?

Comment: You probably should move that "init" function definition to outside the constructor.

Comment: Also there are lots of duplicates for this issue - the key is to make a copy of `this` in another variable declared outside the `.each()` and then use that variable instead of `this`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Copy the `this` reference to a local variable. That way it will be available in the closure of the callback function.

(Side note: You shouldn't set the prototype inside the constructor, that way you would reassign it for each instance that you create.)

```
function buildNameDropdown(data, elem) { 
  this.data = data;
  this.name = $(data).find('nameDetails');
  this.elem = elem;
};

buildNameDropdown.prototype.init = function() {
  $(this.elem).append($('<option value=""> ----- Select a Name ----- </option>')); 
  var t = this;      
  $(this.name).each(function() {
    $(t.elem).append($('<option value="' + $(this).attr('name') + '">' + $(this).attr('name') + '</option>'));
  });
  $(this.elem).combobox(); // from jQuery UI combobox extention
};
```

Comment: Thank you for this, it worked perfect.  As far as moving the prototype outside of the constructor I've seen it before keeping it within in and then wrapping in a condition to see if the function has already been created or not, thus only needing to creating it once and making the code more efficient?  See Lines: 2-19 of the source code of this URL [http://einstein.etsu.edu/~pittares/CSCI3110/examples/6-13.htm](http://einstein.etsu.edu/~pittares/CSCI3110/examples/6-13.htm)

Comment: @WizzyBoom: Yes, that would only set the prototype once, but it makes the creation of the objects less efficient as you still have to make that check every time. I would rather wrap the constructor and the prototype in a function expression that returns the constructor, to keep it together.